# How to: capture output from void method through the console?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application, readline, prime-factoring

I'm writing a test case for a prime number program. I'm trying to compare the output of my `PrimeEvaluator` method with my `expectedFactors1` string. `PrimeEvaluator` is a *void* so that is why I'm trying to read the output from the console.

```
public void PrimeTest()
{
    //arange
    int number = 738;
    string expectedFactors1 = "2,3,3,41";
    string actual;

    //act
    Primes.Program.PrimeEvaluator( number);
    actual = Console.ReadLine();

    //assert
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedFactors1,actual);           
}
```

When I run my unit test nothing happens. I know this is probably wrong, but could someone give me some insight as to how to capture that output of numbers from `PrimeEvaluator`?

Comment: Show prime evaluater

Comment: And why can't you make your PrimeEvaluator method return the answer so you can deal with the output in whatever fashion you see fit? Just make the method return a list of ints.

Comment: void is the only return type that seems suitable because the class checks for several conditions. I tried to make it an int but it says "not all code paths return a value"

Comment: @MickyD silly mocked method? You do know what unit testing means right? You are giving him terrible advice in coupling his prime evaluation method to the console output.

Comment: @PmanAce I beg to differ.   User interface testing is performed by the same due-diligent method irrespective of whether the app is Web; WPF; WinForms or a console app.  A UI is a UI is a UI.  The only benefit of testing cracking open an API just to test a method directly is to increase test code coverage which by the way does little in the way of proving say my flight management computer works correctly because it does not test the entire use case.  Have fun mocking and not testing what is actually important.  https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/have-you-unit-tested-that-aileron-servo/

Comment: Why are you assuming I would mock anything? Ui testing is for testing Ui elements only, like button executing associated commands, Ui element positioning, proper front end business logic, etc... not backend business logic which this clearly is! Thanks for the down vote by the way without commenting.

Comment: Why are you defending your anti testing spiel with your own blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply make your PrimeEvaluator method return a list of integers. Then you can compare the output without having to parse the console, which is never a good idea. Here is how you could change your method to return an integer list:

```
private static List<int> PrimeEvaluator(int number)
    {
        var result = new List<int>();

        // Take out the 2s
        while (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            result.Add(2);

            number /= 2;
        }

        // take out other primes
        int factor = 3;

        while (factor * factor <= number)
        {
            if (number % factor == 0)
            {
                result.Add(factor);

                number /= factor;
            }
            else
                factor += 2;
        }

        // if num is not 1, then whatever is left is prime.
        if (number > 1) result.Add(number);

        return result;
    }
```

And then to call this in your unit test (you have 2 ways to compare):

```
List<int> primeFactorsList = PrimeEvaluator(738); // list variant
string primeFactorsString = string.Join(", ", primeFactorsList); // string variant
```

which returns a list with 4 ints: 2, 3, 3, 41

Now your code can be reused in a library, no need to depend on the Console output for the answer.

On a side note, have a look at the System.Math code in .Net to see how Microsoft implements the available math operations, the source code is available:  [System.Math](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/math.cs,a4407e67b9a5afad)

Comment: Every time you do Console.Write() with a number, just add it instead to your integer list and return the list at the end of your method.

Comment: Seems like a good approach. Could you give me an idea of what that would look like for the for loop near the end of `PrimeEvaluator`?. Since you dont know exactly what the number will be?

Comment: _"without having to parse the console, which is never a good idea"_ - sooo user interface testing is a bad idea then?  I think not.  Check out _Ranorex_ and _Selenium_.  Also what if `PrimeEvaluator` is a contract implementation?  Contracts might not be happy if they are changed just to suit a unit test.   Anyway, perhaps you should include code for your answer?

Comment: if parsing the console isn't a bad idea, how can i do it in this situation so that i can save it to a variable?

Comment: @DavidKenyon96 screen-scraping just like any other UI-based testing.  They **all** do it

Comment: Sorry I'm not on my computer, I'll be able to show you an example tomorrow when I get home. As for needing the UI to unit test a function, that is not unit testing, you're violating separation of concerns and single responsibility principle. Also front end unit testing is for front end layers, not really the case here.

Comment: Also UI unit tests are at the top of the testing pyramid after having unit tested individual units in your code, like your evaluator function.

Comment: @MickyD This is testing presentation logic and "business" logic simultaneously, which is more than a _unit test_ should do, and also points to unnecessary coupling in the code since they're strongly bound together now. Testing the UI isn't bad, or a bad idea, but testing the UI to validate that a function that does prime factorization returns the correct values *is*, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you can tap into the [`Console.Out`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out(v=vs.110).aspx) using [`Console.SetOut()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) to intercept what is written to it.

```
public void PrimeTest() {        
    //stream and writer used to intercept console output
    using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()) {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        Console.SetOut(writer);

        //Arrange
        int number = 738;
        string expectedFactors1 = "2, 3, 3, 41";

        //Act
        Primes.Program.PrimeEvaluator(number);

        //Assert
        memoryStream.Position = 0; //reset position to read stream
        string actual = new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedFactors1, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly how I want to do it. The test case runs now, but it returns failed. This is what i get in return: "Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<2, 3, 3, 41,>. Actual:<>. "
It's not showing anything under the Actual:<> part, meaning it might not be reading from the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidKenyon96 forgot to reset the memory stream position.

Comment: Small note, you should show him the proper way of using streams, by closing them explicitly or with the using keyword...